# numpy array and matrix multiplication - returns matrix

Tags: numpy, matrix-multiplication

I want to multiply array and matrix in an iterative fashion:

```
for i in range(n):
    V = np.dot(M, V)
```

but the `np.dot` returns a matrix. I can obviously cast the matrix to numpy array, but is there a normal way to perform this task?

Comment: numpy does not have 'vectors'; just arrays (which may be 1d). `matrix` is a subclass that is always 2d, and funtions using it usually return the same thing.  Avoid that class if it confuses you.  You expresion needs editing.

Answer (score 1):

to expand on what @hpaulj said:

I guess your initialization code is something like

```
V = np.array([1,2,3])
M = np.matrix([
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]])
```

Sorry for the confusion, but the general advice is: don't use the matrix **class**, ever. Just use `np.array`

```
V = np.array(...)
M = np.array(...)
```

np.dot works fine with two `array`s

The matrix class was put in because before python 3.5 there was no independent **matmul** operator, and people wanted a way to say `M*V` and get matrix multiplication (In 3.5 you can say: `V@M`). the matrix class causes more problems than it solves. Any code that's expecting one and gets the other will just be wrong.

You're doing the right thing using `np.dot`, for this particular problem there's also [np.linalg.matrix_power](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.matrix_power.html)

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I didn't knew the thing about the matrix class, nor the easy way to raise a matrix to a power.